# Twitter4j search through user's friends

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I'm developing an Android application in which I want to send a Twitter direct message to a logged in user's friend. I'm using Twitter4J to access the API.

I retrieve the friend list through the twitter.getFriendsList method. This works ok, but I also need to search through the friends based on there name, I tried through twitter.searchUser method, but this searches through all twitter users, and not through my followers. Is there a method that I'm missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

getFriendsList returns a `PagableResponseList<User>` lets call what is returned `users` so if you need to search through that you use

```
 for (User friend : users) 
 { 
     if(friend.getScreenName().equals("whateverYouAreSearchingOn"))
     {
         twitter.sendDirectMessage(friend.getId(), "The Direct Message");
     }
 }
```

Or else I'm not sure what you are asking here :)

Comment: What I wanted is that I wouldn't have to get all the user's friends in order to do the search. But send the query text to Twitter's server and get back only the friends that match the query.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding for what you searching.  Is it something like "all friends that contain 'Official' in the screen name"?  Or "all friends who have tweeted 'xyz'"?  Could you explain further?